# How i show cart page content after redirecting

Tags: checkout, cart, frontend

I have to redirect cart page link /checkout/cart to http://lab.ghrix.com/eee_neha/checkout/winkelwagen/ .After redirect the cart page content not show on /checkout/winkelwagen/. How i show the cart page content on /checkout/winkelwagen/.

Comment: Hi user, please explain what you have done (Controller overwrite, config.xml, layout.xml) and what doesn't work exactly. Please EDIT your question, then request reopening.

Answer (score 1):

You have add the code in your layout file. Add this code in your handle
`<yourfrontname_checkout_winkelgen>`

```
<yourfrontname_checkout_winkelgen>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
        <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
        <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" translate="label">
            <label>Empty Shopping Cart Content Before</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
            <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml" after="-" />
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
            <label>Shopping Cart Items Before</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
            <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
        </block>

        <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.extra" translate="label">
            <label>Checkout Forms Extra</label>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" translate="label">
            <label>Shopping Cart Items After</label>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
    </block>
</reference>
</yourfrontname_checkout_winkelgen>
```

Comment: I had created a module to redirect the url .I had created config.xml and Url.php in model.My code is: etc/config.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <Ghrix_Newcart>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </Ghrix_Newcart>
 </modules>
  <global>
    <rewrite>
      <ghrix_newcart_checkout_cart>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/winkelwagen#]]></from>
        <to>/checkout/cart</to>
      </ghrix_newcart_checkout_cart>
    </rewrite>
   <models>
      <ghrix_newcart>
        <class>Ghrix_Newcart_Model</class>
      </ghrix_newcart>
      <core>
        <rewrite>
          <url>Ghrix_Newcart_Model_Url</url>
        </rewrite>
      </core>
    </models>
  </global> 
</config>

Comment: <?php
class Ghrix_Newcart_Model_Url extends Mage_Core_Model_Url {
 public function getUrl($routePath = null, $routeParams = null) {
  if(strstr($routePath,'checkout')){
}
  if ( $routePath == 'checkout/cart' ) {    
     $routePath = 'checkout/winkelwagen';
   }
   return parent::getUrl($routePath, $routeParams);
  }
} 
?>

Comment: This code in model/url.php. I have change the url checkout/cart to checkout/winkelwagen. But i didn't get the  content of cart page .Please suggest how i get the cart page content on checkout/winkelwagen

Comment: refer this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643

Comment: I already created module .Please suggest me how can I get cart page data /content on my url. Its rewrite the url to checkout/winkelwagen but didn't get cart page content. Please suggest how i get the content?

Comment: you have to add router and layout for your module.

Comment: Please suggest me how. Please tell me the whole procedure

Comment: ask to google, you will get more reference